# Springboot API returns empty response

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I built a simple Springboot API which is hooked up to a H2 db that contains some test data. However when I hit the API endpoint I get an empty response.

```
[{}]
```

When I debug my application the user object that is returned by the controller contains the user I am expecting.

[image: Debugged user object]

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/user")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserController(@Autowired UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Set<User> getAllUsers(){
        final Set<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
        return users;
    }
}
```

UserRepo.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT usr from User usr")
    Set<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

UserService.java

```
public interface UserService {

    Set<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository repository;

    public UserServiceImpl(@Autowired UserRepository userRepository){
        this.repository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<User> getAllUsers(){
        final Set<User> users = repository.getAllUsers();
        return users;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String role;
    private String premium;
}
```

Comment: Show some code what you wrote

Comment: Please show the method in `@Controller` and `User` class, otherwise it would be guessing.

Comment: Just updated the post with the code @Ramesh

Comment: ..and the `User` class.

Comment: Make sure you are not using `@Transient` on the User's fields and you are generating getters for them.

Comment: Added User.java to the post

Comment: Try adding setters on `User`. The JSON converter might expect them for bean-related reasons.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return ResponseEntity.ok().body(users)` instead of just `return users` in the controller and the return type `ResponseEntity<Set<User>>`?

Comment: I am unsure on why this is however, I removed Getter & Setter and created them manually... Now it returns the user. Seems to be some issue with using lombok

Comment: Did you try with Lombok generated setters too though? If the converter identifies properties by them having both a getter and a setter, having getters wouldn't be enough. It's unlikely that Lombok by itself would affect it, as it generates the method at compile time so there shouldn't be a difference between generated ones and hand written ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a rather strange issue of which I am still unable to say which. However, removing lombok's `@getter` and `@setter` annotations then implementing traditional ones fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to set the class members of `User` public to allow jackson serialise them, i.e.,

```
// User.java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String username;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String email;
    public String role;
    public String premium;
}
```

**Note**: if you'd like to not serialise a field, use `@JsonIgnore` instead of setting it as private, e.g.,

```
@Entity
public class User {
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    public String role;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just remove final and change Set to List as well.
and you really don`t need to do like this:

```
public UserController(@Autowired UserService userService)
```

Just remove this method and add `Autowired` up to `userService` filed.
Because final object can`t be cast to json string.
remove this as well:

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE</h3>
```

Comment: "Because final object can`t be cast to json string.". That's just not true.